# Clone Git Repo URL from TFS in to XCODE VPN Connected

Tags: swift, xcode, git, tfs, vpn

I have an issue to Clone Git Repo Url from TFS to Xcode (**VPN Connected**). But I can access via Terminal and  I tried git clone, pull and push and it is working . I tried **SourceControl/Clone** Entered Clone repository URL with same username and password credential which i tried in terminal and getting **Aunteication failed** . Url also have SSH but I don't know how to clone directly from Xcode.Please help.

Comment: Do you use PAT as the password for authentication? You can try to only input PAT(created with full scopes) for password (leave username empty).

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.